# Counting Likes and shared times in google reader public profile

Tags: google-reader

We've collected a list of google reader profiles of our members and now I want to make a hot list board and show the most shared and the most liked items to be shared with our members.

I've checked a couple of unofficial google reader APIs but I did not find anything related to the **like** or **sharing**.

do you know how can I count the number of likes for each feed item in the shared profile of our members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likes are exposed in the Atom feed for the shared items as gr:likingUser elements (one per user who liked the item, up to 100). Additional likers (and their profile information) can be fetched by making a GET request to http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/item/likers?i=. http://blog.persistent.info/2009/07/exporting-likes-from-google-reader.html has more information.

Comment: thanks that was great help. I just prepared a simple prototype now. Another feature asked is ranking members based on their followers. I couldn't find how to count just google reader followers. any clue?